# Error handling at component level in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to do error handling at component level. If I inject error handler at component level, it does not work. But the same injected at module level works fine.

Code that works:-

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  ***providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: AppErrorHandler}]***,
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  ***providers: []***
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private errorHandler: ErrorHandler) {}

  title = 'ErrorHandlerDemo';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    (this.errorHandler as AppErrorHandler).errorObservable.subscribe((err) => console.log(err));
  }

}
```

Now if any error happens anywhere in module, it is caught by the AppErrorHandler.

Code that does not work:-

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  ***providers: []***,
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  ***providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: AppErrorHandler}]***
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private errorHandler: ErrorHandler) {}

  title = 'ErrorHandlerDemo';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    (this.errorHandler as AppErrorHandler).errorObservable.subscribe((err) => console.log(err));
  }

}
```

I expected error handling to work when error handler is injected at component level. But that only works when injected at module level. Can anyone tell me why that is happening?

Comment: Then use the first option: it works, and the error handler *is* injected in the component. If you **provide** an error handler in the component, then only that component will use the error handler, and not all the unrelated services that actually produce errors, which will still use the module-provided, default error handler.

Comment: @JBNizet I can use the first option. But the thing which is bothering me is why injecting the error handler at component does not work. It does not align with how DI works in angular. Am I missing anything? Can you please explain why the second option does not work. Thanks!!

Comment: You're confusing **injecting** and **providing**. As I said already, the first option **does inject** the singleton error handler in the component. If you **provide** a service in a component, then another, different instance of the service is created for each instance of the component. So, Angular keeps notifying the singleton error handler provided at the module level whenever there is an error, but your component expects to find errors in a different error handler instance created specifically for your component.

Comment: @lastride793 - Did you ever find a way to do this at the component level? I'd like to override my app's ErrorHandler on a particular page.